# Strip index as Pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a table with a single index column looking like this:

```
              1   2   3
Monday_0    NaN NaN NaN
Monday_1    NaN NaN NaN
Tuesday_2   NaN NaN NaN
Tuesday_3   NaN NaN NaN
```

I want to keep the index, but want the first part of the index into a new column. In other words, it should look like this:

```
              1   2   3 Day
Monday_0    NaN NaN NaN Monday
Monday_1    NaN NaN NaN Monday
Tuesday_2   NaN NaN NaN Tuesday
Tuesday_3   NaN NaN NaN Tuesday
```

So I have tried a number of different solutions:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['Day'] = str(df['index']).split('_')
```

This give me the whole series per row.

```
df['Day'] = str(df.index.split('_')[0])
```

Doesn't work as index does not have a split function

```
df['Day'] = df.index.as_type('str').split('_')[0]
```

Doesn't work as index does not have a as_type function

```
df.index.set_levels(df.index.get_level_values(level = 1).str.split('_')[0], 
                level = 1, inplace=True)
```

Doesn't work as 'Index' object has no attribute 'set_levels'. I guess it only works with multi index?

And with that I am all out of ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `str.split`

```
df['Day']=df.index.str.split('_').str[0]
df
Out[219]: 
            1   2   3      Day
Monday_0  NaN NaN NaN   Monday
Monday_1  NaN NaN NaN   Monday
Tuesday_2 NaN NaN NaN  Tuesday
Tuesday_3 NaN NaN NaN  Tuesday
```